# Images not showing after moving site

Tags: images, database, links

I've tried all the options suggested in other similar questions, and I'm stuck.
My images are not showing after moving a site from my local machine to another server.  I've searched the database, and there is no trace of the old domain, so using a search and replace won't help.
I've checked the wpconfig and there is no trace of the old domain.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

If I check the media library, the files are all there and they have the correct URLs (the new server), but the links to them in the site are to the old local server.

Comment: have you tried flushing your permalinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a search via PHPMyAdmin did not show up any instances of the wrong URL.  However, when I searched and replaced using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/ I found certain URLs were incorrect.

Some changes could not be made with the plugin as they were serialized.